# C++ - Deleting a node in doubly linked list causes a segmentation fault

Tags: c++, linked-list, segmentation-fault, doubly-linked-list

I'm trying to delete a node by its position, and the line delete item in the code below causes the seg fault, I have been trying to figure this out for a while but I counldn't.
Here is the remove method:

```
void* List::remove(long index){
  if(index > this->size-1){
    return NULL;
  }
  else {
    long i = 0;
    List::ListItem *item = this->head;

    while(i <= this->size-1){
      if(index == 0){
          item->getNext()->setPrev(NULL);
          this->head = item;
          this->size--;
          delete item;
          break;
      }

      else if(indexOf(item->getData()) == index){
          item->getPrev()->setNext(this->head->getNext());
          item->getNext()->setPrev(this->head->getPrev());
          this->size --;
          break;
      }
      else {
          item = item->getNext();
          i++;
      }
   }
 }
 return NULL;
}
```

Comment: The right tool to solve such problems is your debugger. You should step through your code line-by-line *before* asking on Stack Overflow. For more help, please read [How to debug small programs (by Eric Lippert)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). At a minimum, you should \[edit] your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example that reproduces your problem, along with the observations you made in the debugger.

Comment: Also this algorithm is not worth adding in a linked list implementation. Not what lists are for.

Comment: @DeiDei Whats wrong with my algorithm? Could you be more precise please?

Comment: @ChandlerBing Your algorithm is fine, but it's wasteful seeing as linked lists were not made to be accessed by indices in the first place. Instead of removing an element given by an index, have your function take an iterator to the element you want to remove, that will turn your algorithm from O(n) to O(1). (Look at the way std::list is done.)

Comment: Why not use `std::list`?

Answer (score 0):

Your algorithm has some issues. Here are some corrections with minor comments to point on the corrections.

```
void/* * */ List::remove(long index){
  if(index > this->size-1){
    return /* NULL */;
  }
  else {
    long i = 0;
    List::ListItem *item = this->head;

    while(i <= this->size-1 && i <= index /* new */){
      if(index == 0){
          item->getNext()->setPrev(this->head->getPrev() /* NULL */); 
          this->head->getPrev()->setNext(item->getNext()); // new
          this->head = item->getNext();
          this->size--;
          delete item;
          break;
      }
      else if(indexOf(item->getData()) == index){
          item->getPrev()->setNext(item /* this->head*/ ->getNext());
          item->getNext()->setPrev(item /* this->head */ ->getPrev());
          this->size --;
          break;
      }
      else {
          item = item->getNext();
          i++;
      }
   }
 }
 return /* NULL */;
}
```

A segfault occur if `index == 0`. Your list always starts with `item` even `item` is deleted. You have to change `this->head` to the right cell - the next after item - in such a case.

You should take some time to draw your linked list on a paper and to verify the invariants. If you draw the different cases, you will have an explanation for the second case.

Comment: Our teacher gave us a class diagram and I'm just implementing it, I found it wierd two